# jquery horizontal clip

Tags: javascript, jquery, clip

so I wanted a similar effect to this one:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Clip

but i want the horizontal clipping to happen only from left to right or from right to left ( with a parameter that i will define ), not simultaneously towards the center from both sides. I was wondering how should i modify the jquery code to achieve what i need.

something like :

```
$(this).hide("clip", { direction: "horizontalL" }, 1000);
$(this).hide("clip", { direction: "horizontaLR" }, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try slide:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

or

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

Comment: i would use that if i did not wanted to implement a page flipping system. i think clipping is the way to go for me.